# How to trigger a button click event from the user's browser

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to set up some UI automation in SAP Fiori by adding JavaScript to the page so that when a user loads a form, some fields are prefilled for them, and then it automatically goes to the next screen.

I can't make modifications in the SAP UI, this needs to be done in the browser at runtime.

[image]

I need to trigger the click of the 'Create' button above. The button's DOM id is `__button9`.

However, invoking the normal JavaScript click event doesn't work. I believe the SAP UI framework abstracts these events. So I'm wondering if there's a way to still trigger the underlying SAP event to invoke the click functionality?

Using the [button.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) function doesn't trigger the SAP button click event:

```
const button = document.getElementById('__button9');
button.click();
```

Dispatching the event like this also doesn't work:

```
const clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);

const button = document.getElementById('__button9');

button.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

This is a very product specific question, but a similar question has already been asked on the [SAP support channels here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/747551/dom-element-click-the-button-but-do-not-call-press.html) and didn't receive a response.

[This blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/24/how-i-do-self-study-on-a-given-fiori-control-part-3/) explains the SAP event model pretty well, but the use case of triggering button events from outside the context of the SAP UI Controller doesn't seem to be covered.

Comment: DOM event `.click` seems to be working when I try. At least it's triggering my press event handler. You could try firing the handlers manually perhaps: `sap.ui.getCore().byId("my-id").firePress()`. Also, it's unlikely that it'll always be called `__button9`, better to give a proper ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the SAP forum but haven't tried it yet.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId( $('#navigation button').eq(0).attr("id")).firePress();
```

https://answers.sap.com/questions/10107636/unable-to-trigger-a-click-event-in-onafterrenderin.html

Maybe it helps.

Kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.38/#/api/sap.m.Button/methods/firePress

Controls already have fireEvent method and derivatives in their API as fire+EventName.

```js
var oButton = this.byId("button");
oButton.attachPress(function(oEvent){
    console.log("Pressed!");
});

oButton.firePress();
```